# quitar los apostrofes que estan en un csv con php

Tags: php, csv

tengo un archivo que esta en disco C:/archivo/Catalog.csv este archivo contiene apostrofes dentro de sus líneas, como o con que función de php puedo reemplazar los apostrofes (') por un guion (-) que están dentro del archivo sin abrir el archivo.

tengo este codigo:

```
<?php $path_to_file = 'C:/archivo/Catalog.csv'; $file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file); $file_contents = str_replace("\'",",-",$file_contents); file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents); ?>
```

Comment: El código parece ser correcto, ¿hay algún problema?, ¿no hace los remplazos?, ¿obtienes algún mensaje de error?.

Comment: No da error y no hace nada no reemplaza

Comment: No necesitas escapar el apóstrofe, a menos que sea una cadena encerrada entre comillas simples: `str_replace("'",",-",$file_contents);`

Comment: justamente eso era lo que me faltaba, muchísimas gracias @Triby